# How to get text from ButtonContent with Grid in it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i want to get in my codebehind the Content of an button that has a grid in it with multiple textboxes.

i had this before Code and this works:

XAML:

```
 <Button Click="btnClick_upload_Data">
                            <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="test1" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="test2" ></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            </Button.Content>
 </Button>
```

codebehind:

```
private void btnClick_upload_Data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string s = ((((sender as Button).Content) as StackPanel).Children[1] as TextBlock).Text; 
//…
```

and this way i got the "test2" im my string variable.

**now my XAML has changed a bit**

my Question is how do i have to Change my function so i still get "test2" in my string variable 's'

new XAML:

```
<Button Click="btnClick_upload_Data" >
                            <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                                <TextBlock Text="test1" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="test2" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
```

new XAML:

```
private void btnClick_upload_Data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //????
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps it is a good time to start looking into some MVVM basics (That said, i cannot even understand why you want to do what you are asking in your question - it doesn't really make any sense to me; it looks like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: i dont want to avoid this, i want to solve this. please dont blame me for not working with MVVM because that is not what i asked for. thanks

Comment: Again, your question looks very much like a XY problem. Your approach seems very broken if you need to (programmatically) extract some string from some UI label to do things in your program logic. Just you insisting in doing it doesn't make it a good idea to do it...

Comment: @dymanoid sorry this was my old Code, didnt notice it. i used this Code: 
            string s = ((((sender as Button).Content) as StackPanel).Children[1] as TextBlock).Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void btnClick_upload_Data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = null;
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    StackPanel sp = btn.Content as StackPanel;
    if (sp != null && sp.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        Grid grid = sp.Children[0] as Grid;
        if (grid != null && grid.Children.Count > 1)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = grid.Children[1] as TextBlock;
            if (textBlock != null)
                s = textBlock.Text;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: sorry had no time to answer… no it did not, i think you didnt see that the textboxes are inside the grid. but still thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: @adriasnk22: They weren't until you edited the question...I have now edited my answer based on your edit.